# Keyboard access is not working for inside div with buttons when user hovers the div we are displaying buttons. How to implement accessibility?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have div container with two buttons. When user mouse hover or keyboard focus I am showing that button. I am not able to access those button through keyboard.

Below is my sample HTML and CSS code.

```
<div class="ui-col ui-dropzone" tabindex="0">
    <div class="ui-edit-bar">
        <div class="label"></div>
        <button tabindex="0" data-action="edit">Edit Row</button>
        <button tabindex="0" data-action="edit">Edit Col</button>
    </div>
</div>

.ui-col:hover, .ui-col:focus {
  border: 1px dashed #17a2b8;
}

.ui-edit-bar {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.ui-col:hover > .ui-edit-bar,  
.ui-col:focus > .ui-edit-bar {
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

Able to access div using keyboard. But I am not able to access buttons through keyboard.

Comment: Is this a question or a simple statement?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is causing the problem.

You only display the edit bar when the `<div class="ui-col ui-dropzone" tabindex="0">` is focused.

When you focus an item within that div it no longer has focus, so it reverts to `display: none;` and that then hides the `<button>`s from the accessibility tree.

You could use the [:focus-within](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within) pseudo selector and make the parent opacity 0 but the support is not great for `:focus-within` yet.

```css
.ui-col.ui-dropzone{
  opacity: 0;
}
.ui-col.ui-dropzone:hover,
.ui-col.ui-dropzone:focus-within{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-col ui-dropzone">
    <div class="ui-edit-bar">
        <div class="label"></div>
        <button data-action="edit">Edit Row</button>
        <button data-action="edit">Edit Col</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Realistically though (due to poor support for `:focus-within`) you would likely need a JavaScript fallback that changes the parent class when a button is focused and use that to control the opacity.

The advantage of this approach is that you are not having to add `tabindex="0"` everywhere so you code will be easier to maintain.